# How to access flexlm license thorugh another server

Tags: networking, license, simulation

There is a server,lets call it mainserver running flexlm to distribute a license file.

Now, Mainserver provides license only to specific mac addresses on the network.
Let X be be a computer running ubuntu 14.04, on this network with access to mainserver.

Let Y be a machine on same network but without access to Mainserver,
How would Y go about accessing the license file???

I have complete access to X, and Y with regards to priviliges.

the license file in question is modelsim

Please don't answer such as to spoof the mac of X on Y

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: "Please don't answer such as to spoof the mac of X on Y" - Why?  You either need to add the actual MAC address of the client in question or spoof the MAC address of another client.

Comment: @Xavierjazz I have no idea what to try, But I feel like we can run a flexlm server on X which licenses from main server than Y can license X , is it possible , or maybe use a proxy/vpn server on X?

Comment: @Ramhound I thought it was a bit obvious,anyways "Spoofing isn't a possible solution because both X and Y would be running at same time but due to spoof one would lose access because of conflicts, " 
Secondly, not asked in the question but still a thought "There might be more devices like Y and spoofing doesn't allow for concurrent access" .TY

Comment: @user2984602 - Updated your question.  What is left unsaid is not obvious.  If you don't have the ability or authorization to add a new MAC address to the whitelist then find somebody who does.